# Header/Footer formatting on Title page

Tags: header-footer, titles, fancyhdr, abstract

I've spent the best part of an hour trying to make a footer/header on my title page and I'm getting so frustrated, any help appreciated.

I just need my university name at the top and my supervisor at the bottom. I've tried various things, the only thing that's worked was overriding the `{empty}` style with a head and footer. But then when I try to make an abstract paragraph on the next page, its putting the same header and footer in there. I think its because the abstract uses `\thispagestyle{empty}` as well, but I don't know how to override it. Any help appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{\iffloatpage{0pt}{0.4pt}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{\iffloatpage{0pt}{0.4pt}}
\fancyhead[L]{\iffloatpage{}{University}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\iffloatpage{}{Supervisor}}

\begin{document}


\title{\textbf{Title here}}
\author{My name}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\newpage


\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here....
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why the hell do you want a header and a footer on a title page? That's against all typographical traditions!

Comment: If you want to get really fancy, see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273868/size-and-position-of-boxes-in-title-page/273885?s=2|2.0850#273885

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation and [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993)

Answer (score 1):

I think creating a custom titlepage is more suited than to fiddle with page headers and footers.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    University
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
        {\LARGE\bfseries Title here \bigbreak}
        {\large My name \medbreak}
        \today
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    Supervisor
\end{titlepage}
\begin{abstract}
    Abstract goes here....
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly say, the page style that is used in the `report` class on the page with a title is `empty`.  You can redefine this using `\fancypagestyle{empty}{....}`.  In order to restrict these effects to just the title page you should put the command in the body of the document, rather than the preamble, and enclose it together with the title page itself in a group `\bgroup...\egroup`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\bgroup
\fancypagestyle{empty}{\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[L]{University}
\fancyfoot[C]{Supervisor}}

\title{\textbf{Title here}}
\author{My name}
\maketitle


\newpage
\egroup

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here....
\end{abstract}

Text.
\end{document}
```