# How to use fancyhdr and \begin{titlepage} concurrently

Tags: fancyhdr

Im writing a thesis in Latex and am trying to create a title page with a the `fancyhdr` package. However the right header Swinburne University of Technology (Sarawak Campus) refuses to appear on the title page. Could someone please help me to fix this? Below is the code and the default title page.

url = http://ge.tt/2CwKfBZ2

```
  \begin{titlepage}
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}

        \Large
        \textbf{Swinburne University of Technology \\Sarawak Campus\\ Faculty of Engineering, Computing \& Sciences}

        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \Large
        Modelling of an Involute Spur Gear via Finite Element Method


        \vspace{1.5cm}

        Bachelor of Engineering\\
        (Mechanical)

        \vspace{0.8cm}

        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Swinburne}

        \Large
        Name\\
        June/2016

    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document, not just fragements. The link given above leads to an 'attacking' site. I won't pursue this.

Comment: `fancyhdr` used on the titlepage sounds very very wrong. [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209993) and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Comment: If you are comfortable with tikz, see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273868/size-and-position-of-boxes-in-title-page/273885?s=2|2.0916#273885  Tikzpagenodes also defines (current page header area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [concur with Johannes_B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300930/how-to-use-fancyhdr-and-begintitlepage-concurrently#comment729004_300930) that using [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) is probably not the way to go here, unless you want the university name header to appear on every page of your document anyway. Instead, I used a manual approach to create the headline using `\raggedleft` for flush right  alignment and a `\rule`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        {\raggedleft\textit{Swinburne University of Technology (Sarawak Campus)}\\}
        \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

        \vspace*{1cm}

        \Large
        \textbf{Swinburne University of Technology \\Sarawak Campus\\ Faculty of Engineering, Computing \& Sciences}

        \vspace{\fill}

        \Large
        Modelling of an Involute Spur Gear via Finite Element Method

        \vspace{\fill}

        Bachelor of Engineering\\
        (Mechanical)

        \vspace{1cm}

        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Swinburne}

        \vspace{\fill}

        \Large
        Name

        \vspace{\fill}

        June/2016
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: title page as produced by the example document]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i was looking for... Thank you