# How do I put an image on the top leftside on Latex?

Tags: graphics, positioning

I am working in my master thesis, which I am writting with Latex, and I need to put the logo of my university in the title page in two places: On the top left hand side and in the middle of the page. The following image shows how it should be appearing: 
[image]

In order to do so, I have created the following latex code:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{-1.2in}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=13cm]{logouc3m}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{-0.5in}    
\large{\textbf{\color{Blue}Master universitario...}} \\
\large{\textbf{\color{Blue}Indique el curso academico (ej: 2014-2015}} \\
\vspace*{0.3in}
\Large{\it{Trabajo Fin de Máster}} \\
\vspace*{0.3in}
\begin{LARGE}
    \textbf{\color{Blue}"Titulo del trabajo"} \\
\end{LARGE}
\vspace*{0.15in}
\color{Blue}\rule{110mm}{0.1mm}\\
\vspace*{0.15in}
\begin{LARGE}
    \textbf{\color{Blue} Nombre Apellido1 Apellido2} \\
\end{LARGE}
\vspace*{0.1in}
\begin{large}
    \textbf{\color{Blue} Tutor\textbackslash es} \\
    \vspace*{0.1in}
    \textbf{\color{Blue} Nombre Apellido1 Apellido2} \\
    \vspace*{0.05in}
    \textbf{\color{Blue} Nombre Apellido1 Apellido2}
\end{large}
\end{center}    
\end{titlepage}
```

But I have not found the way to add the logo of the university on the top left side. I tried using the command:

```
\begin{ \begin{flushleft}
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{logouc3m}
\end{flushleft}
```

Right before the center enviroment, but it does not work properly.

Comment: This question may be of use: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page

Comment: I would use fancyheadings, define a head with the image and change the head after titlepage.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273868/size-and-position-of-boxes-in-title-page

Comment: Dont use the figure envrionment. It creates a float, but this image should not float.

Comment: If the problem has been solved, please mark a solution and upvote what helped you. If the problem has not been solved, please refine your question.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like  this?

*Note:* The logo exists in `.svg` format. I had to convert it to `.pdf`. Also, don't use the `figure` environment for an image that doesn't have to float, and has no caption.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\colorlet{Blue}{blue}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \vspace*{-1.2in}
  \begin{flushleft}
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logouc3m}
  \end{flushleft}
  \begin{center}
    \large{\textbf{\color{Blue}Master universitario...}} \\
    \large{\textbf{\color{Blue}Indique el curso academico (ej: 2014-2015)}} \\
    \vspace*{0.3in}
    \Large{\it{Trabajo Fin de Máster}} \\
    \vspace*{0.3in}
    \begin{LARGE}
      \textbf{\color{Blue}"Titulo del trabajo"} \\
    \end{LARGE}
    \vspace*{0.15in}
    \color{Blue}\rule{110mm}{0.1mm}\\
    \vspace*{0.15in}
    \begin{LARGE}
      \textbf{\color{Blue} Nombre Apellido1 Apellido2} \\
    \end{LARGE}
    \vspace*{0.1in}
    \begin{large}
      \textbf{\color{Blue} Tutor\textbackslash es} \\
      \vspace*{0.1in}
      \textbf{\color{Blue} Nombre Apellido1 Apellido2} \\
      \vspace*{0.05in}
      \textbf{\color{Blue} Nombre Apellido1 Apellido2}
    \end{large}
  \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\noindent\parbox{\linewith}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{<path>}\\
Text below the picture}
\vspace{-30pt}%if needed

\begin{center}
some stuff
\end{center}    
\end{titlepage}
```