# Creating a title page like a book

Tags: titles

after looking over internet all the day and trying stuff, i can't create a beautiful title page like this book.

[image: First exemple]

So i'm basically trying to get something with a pictures, and not a white background. I tried using the wallpaper package with a black pictures, but after i can't add blue box with text over it. I would be really happy if someone can help me making a title page like this one. :)

Comment: I guess our moderator can answer the question, but i fear the title wasn't even typeset using LaTeX. I know the book was not typeset with LaTeX.

Comment: This might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273868/size-and-position-of-boxes-in-title-page/273885?s=2|2.0596#273885

Comment: There might be inspiration for you here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85904/showcase-of-beautiful-title-page-done-in-tex

Comment: Show us your MWE then we can help you to edit the blue box with text

Comment: @Johannes_B Which is ... odd .... Not the cover. That's not surprising. But the text.

Comment: @cfr Why? The publisher has a certain workflow which not includes LaTeX. Just because the book is about LaTeX ...

Comment: I think I would go for a graphic editor for something like this rather than a typesetting program... you can fry an egg in a pot, but a pan is easier...