# Image in title page not properly placed

Tags: graphics, titles

I have written title page as below:

```
\title{
    {\textbf{Structural Health Assessment\\
of Railway Bridges\\ 
 Using Computational Intelligence Techniques}
}
\author{\textbf{Sitesh Kumar Singh}\\
\vspace{.6cm}
 (Roll No.: 15CE91S02) \\
 \vspace{.6cm}
 Under the Supervision of \\
 \textbf{Prof. Nirjhar Dhang}
}\\
\vspace{1cm}
    {\includegraphics{university.jpg}\\
    {\large Department of Civil Engineering,\\
Indian Institute of technology, Kharagpur
}}
}
```

In the output pdf file 'image and department name' is placed in the middle of page whereas I want them to be at the bottom of the page as has been written above. Please help.

Comment: You didn't provide any information about page layout and used document class, so you left us guessing :-(. For example, try replace `\vspace{1cm}` with `\vfill`. It could help. Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: BTW, you don't HAVE to use \maketitle to format a title page.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273868/size-and-position-of-boxes-in-title-page/273885?s=3|2.1111#273885 for example.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with the `titling` package (remove the `showframe` option of geometry for the final version):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[vmargin=2.5cm, textwidth=15cm, bindingoffset=6mm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titling}
\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\bfseries\Large \onehalfspacing}
\title{Structural Health Assessment\\
of Railway Bridges\\
 Using Computational Intelligence Techniques}%
\posttitle{\end{center}}
\preauthor{\bfseries\large\vspace{3.5cm}}
 \author{Sitesh Kumar Singh}%\\
 \postauthor{%
 \normalfont
\smallskip\par
 (Roll No.: 15CE91S02)\vspace{1.5cm} \\
Under the Supervision of\\[1ex]
\textbf{Prof. Nirjhar Dhang}
}

\date{}

\renewcommand\maketitlehookd{\vfill\centering\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{kgp}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlingpage}
\setlength\droptitle{10ex}
```

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    %\centering
    \maketitle\clearpage
    \end{titlingpage}

```
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Bernard Sir for the help!! But except top title my other details are getting left aligned. I am using following packages:

Comment: \documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Allows to import images
\usepackage{float} %Allows for control of float positions
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

Comment: May kindly look into please, if possible...Regards, Sitesh

Comment: @Sitesh Singh: I've redone the layout according to your indications. I supposed the logo had to remain centred, though. Hope I'm not wrong. Anyway it's easy to change.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bernard Sir! Your suggestion was exactly what I needed.  I am grateful to you for the prompt help!!