# Designing thesis cover page per exact requirements

Tags: titles

I am trying to recreate this:

[image]

I got the images correct, but not the title and detail.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{thesis}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-1.5pt,xshift=1pt]%
        at (current page.north west)
        {\includegraphics[height=35mm]{logo.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south west)
              {\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{lnu.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}]
```

Comment: Don't use multiple  tikz pictures to do everything in one and load the tikz `calc` library then you can do coordinate calculations. The image you are trying to recreate do you have that in PDF? Because then you can place it in the background and then place stuff on top and adjust until happy. That's how I normally recreate Word templates in LaTeX

Comment: I do not have images in pdf but I can try to convert them. How can I write at the bottom because whenever I have tried, it goes on next page or the title page goes on next page.

Comment: which package and environment I should use to put above two images on same page without disturbing text besides them?

Comment: You're designing a title page, make everything using tikz! The text can be put into `\parbox{width}{text}` inside text nodes. That is what I meant by using a PDF as a background a placing stuff on top.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273868/size-and-position-of-boxes-in-title-page

Comment: Thanks @ John Kormylo