# A letter head with top and bottom logos, page numbers starting with zero

Tags: fancyhdr, letters

```tex
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top =2.5 cm, bottom = 2.5 cm, left = 2 cm, right =2 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[user,savepos]{zref}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
%\cfoot{\thepage\ of \zpageref{LastPage}}
%\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\setcounter{page}{0}
%\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}

%\setcounter{page}{0}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
%\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\vspace*{-2.2 cm}
\includegraphics[width=0.24\linewidth, height=0.08\textheight]{ISA_Logo.jpg}
\end{flushleft}
\begin{center}
\textbf{International Solar Alliance}\\
\textbf{Solar E Mobility: Charging for Change}\\
\textbf{Duration: 120 min}\\
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Agenda}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
    \begin{footnotesize}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{4cm} |p{11cm}|}
            \hline
\textbf{Session} & \textbf{Theme}\\
\hline
Inaugural & Welcome address\\
(3 min) & \\
            \hline
Context setting & Rationale for Solar EV-Integration\\
(5 min)     & \\
\hline
Closing session & Concluding remarks and Vote of thanks \\
(7 min)     & \\
\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{footnotesize}
\end{center}
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=1.05\linewidth, height=0.15\textheight]{isa_bottom.jpg}
\end{flushleft}

\noindent \today
\begin{enumerate}
\item document is attached herewith for your kind reference. 

\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\circledast$}
\item I hav sector. 
\item  I al
\item  I aations. 
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\noindent With the hope
\noindent I look forward to your positive consideration and hearing from you.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, was there a question?

Comment: For a single page (titlepage) one can use a tikzpicture with [overlay, remember picture] to position everything relative to {current page).  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273868/size-and-position-of-boxes-in-title-page

Answer (score 1):

Add to you preamble

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\fancypagestyle{LetterHead}{% Define LetterHead as a new style
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}} % top left
    \fancyfoot[L]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}}%bottom left
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% suppress the line
```

This style put the two logos and suppress the page number.

Inserting

```
\thispagestyle{LetterHead}
```

after `\begin{document}` applies the style only to the first page of the letter.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11 pt, a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top =3.5 cm, bottom = 4.5 cm, left = 2 cm, right =2 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[user,savepos]{zref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%******************************************** added ,,,,,,,,,,,,
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\fancypagestyle{LetterHead}{% Define LetterHead as a new style
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}} % top left
    \fancyfoot[L]{\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-b}}%bottom left
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% suppress the line
%********************************************}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{hyperref} % last  <<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{LetterHead} % apply LetterHead style only in this page <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    \begin{center}
        \textbf{International Solar Alliance}\\
        \textbf{Solar E Mobility: Charging for Change}\\
        \textbf{Duration: 120 min}\\
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{Agenda}
    \end{center}
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{footnotesize}
            \begin{tabular}{|p{4cm} |p{11cm}|}
                \hline
                \textbf{Session} & \textbf{Theme}\\
                \hline
                Inaugural & Welcome address\\
                (3 min) & \\
                \hline
                Context setting & Rationale for Solar EV-Integration\\
                (5 min)     & \\
                \hline
                Closing session & Concluding remarks and Vote of thanks \\
                (7 min)     & \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{footnotesize}
    \end{center}
    
    \noindent \today
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item document is attached herewith for your kind reference. 
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \renewcommand\labelitemi{$\circledast$}
            \item I hav sector. 
            \item  I al
            \item  I actions. 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate}
    \noindent With the hope
    \noindent I look forward to your positive consideration and hearing from you.
    
\end{document}
```