# Create 3 different page layouts to use it in different pages of a book

Tags: minipage, book-design, layout, examdesign

I want to write a textbook, and I want to create 3 different page layouts and use them in different areas of the book. For example: [image]

How can I do this? I am a complete beginner in terms of setting up margins and creating classes in latex but I have been using it for writing math articles for the last 4 years.

Comment: See the restoregeomtry command and its related commands from the geometry package.
As for the leftmost page layout, i think that you would need to use a `minipage`s.

Comment: For true page layouts you need flowfram, although it still requires that the text area include all possible layouts.  Usually headers and footers (which appear automatically on every page) are outside the text area. However it is easier just to format each page using things like paracol and tcolorbox, ending with \newpage or \pagebreak.

Comment: Actually, tikz might be the best approach here.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273868/size-and-position-of-boxes-in-title-page/273885?s=2|2.0686#273885