# How do I make an image span across the page?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, layout

I'm working on a cover page in latex. My current layout and latex code for the image can be seen below. My idea is to make the image span across the entire width of the page. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

```
\centering
\frame{%% frame and fbox put a border around your picture
    \includegraphics[height=0.35\textheight, width=17cm]{images/lookback}%
} %% The frame ends here
```

[image]

Comment: `\centerline{\frame{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,…]{…}}}`. But I would not recommend to use the whole paper width for a framed image. This would be problematic while printing (and cutting).

Comment: `width={\dimexpr \paperwidth-2\fboxsep-2fboxrule}` but how to overlap the margins depends on the document/geometry setup.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273868/size-and-position-of-boxes-in-title-page